# Access variable inside filter function

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

How can I access the searchStr variable within the anonymous function within the `filter` function?  Below searchStr prints 0 - n, I guess an iterator for looping through the collection that I am attempting to filter

```
IEG.vent.on("searchGroups", function (searchStr) {
    if (searchStr) {
        IEG.Router.navigate("search/" + searchStr);
    }
    else {
        IEG.Router.navigate();
    }

    var filteredArray = IEG.searchColl.models.filter(function (model,searchStr) {                
       console.log(model.get("key") + searchStr)
    });
});
```

Comment: Seems like what you're doing should work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `searchStr` from the arguments for your `filter` function:

```
var filteredArray = IEG.searchColl.models.filter(function (model) {   
    console.log(model.get("key") + searchStr);
});
```

Comment: This is the correct answer: The reason is that by adding `searchStr` to the arguments you create a local variable in the anonymous function  that would have to be populated by the `filter` callback. But since the `filter` function doesn't pass the `searchStr` in to the callback you get an undefined variable.  The above code works, because you create a closure, so the anonymous function has access to all variables in the scope chain.